# Python discord.py ways to split output to bypass 2000 character limit

Tags: python, text-files, discord.py

I am attempting to output the contents of a text file to a discord channel via Discord. The issue I have is that there is a 2000 character limit. I have been able to bypass this by using the code below

```
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(73194604108722****)
    channels = ["football"]
    
    
    
    if str(message.channel) in channels:
        if message.content.find("!english") != -1:

            with open('/home/brendan/Desktop/englishfootball.txt', 'r') as file:
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
                await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
```

Running this code leads to a 400 error stating cannot send blank message, which I think is due to there being extra file.read(2000) statements than there is content in the text file (error message below)

```
  File "discordbot.py", line 62, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(file.read(2000).strip())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 856, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed, nonce=nonce)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 225, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

One positive is that all the data is being printed correctly but I just wanted to ask if anyone can think of a better method to do this that would result in the 400 error not showing?

Below is an example of the content of the text file that is being read above

````
Competition English League One - League One Play-off FINAL 
Competitors Oxford United v Wycombe Wanderers 
Match Date Monday, 13th  July 
Match Time ST: 19:30 
Channels: beIN Connect MENA 
   beIN Sports MENA 12 HD 
   beIN Sports MENA 6 HD 
   Nova Sport (bulgaria) / HD 
   Setanta Sports Ukraine+ HD 
   Sky Sports Football UK / HD 
   Sportdigital TV HD 
   SportKlub 6 (slovenia) 
   Stöd 2 Sport 2 / HD 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Competition English Premier League - Week 35 
Competitors Manchester United v Southampton 
Match Date Monday, 13th  July 
Match Time ST: 20:00 
Channels: beIN Connect MENA 
   beIN Sports MENA 11 HD 
   beIN Sports MENA 2 HD 
   Belarus 5 Internet  
   Cosmote Sport 1 HD 
   Cytavision Sports 1 HD 
   DAZN Canada   
   DAZN España   
   Diema Sport 2 HD 
   EuroSport 1 Romania / HD 
   Football HD (tjk) 
   H2 Armenia 
   Idman TV 
   Pick UK / HD 
   Premier Sport HD (cze/svk) 
   RMC Sport 1 HD 
   S Sport 1 (turkey) HD 
   Sky One (uk) / HD 
   Sky Sport 1 / HD Germany 
   Sky Sport Austria 1 HD 
   Sky Sport Football Italia / HD 
   Sky Sport Uno Italia / HD 
   Sky Sports Main Event / HD 
   Sky Sports Premier League / HD 
   Sky Sports Ultra HD (4K) 
   Sport 1 Israel / HD 
   SportKlub 2 (slovenia) 
   SuperSport 3 RSA / HD 
   SuperSport MáXimo 1 RSA 
   TSN Malta 2 HD 
   TV2 Sport Premium HD 
   TV2sumo.no   
   TV3+ (denmark) / HD 
   V Sport Extra HD (sweden) 
   V Sport Jalkapallo HD 
   V Sport Premium HD 
   Varzesh TV 3 Farsi HD 
   ViaPlay (denmark) / HD 
   ViaPlay (finland) / HD 
   ViaPlay (sweden) / HD 
   VOOsport World 1 / HD 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------```


Thanks in advance to anyone who proposes a solution or provides advice.
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just do your read and your send separately and check if the read result is empty before you do your send?

```py
with open('/home/brendan/Desktop/englishfootball.txt', 'r') as file:
    msg = file.read(2000).strip()
    while len(msg) > 0:
        await message.channel.send(msg)
        msg = file.read(2000).strip()
```